# Find all $c\in\mathbb Z^+$ for which $\exists a,b\in\mathbb Z^+, a\neq b$ with $a+c\mid ab$ and $b+c\mid ab$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find all $c\in\mathbb Z^+$ for which $\exists a,b\in\mathbb Z^+, a\neq b$ with $\begin{cases}a+c\mid ab\\b+c\mid ab\end{cases}$
>
> For those $c$, prove only finitely many $(a,b)$ exist.

My attempt:

Let $(a+c,b+c)=d$. Then $\color{RoyalBlue}{d\mid ab}$ and $\text{lcm}(a+c,b+c)\mid ab\iff \frac{(a+c)(b+c)}{d}\mid ab$.

So $d\neq 1$, because $(a+c)(b+c)\mid ab\,\Rightarrow ab\ge (a+c)(b+c)$, impossible.

$a\equiv -c\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv b$ mod $d$. Then $\color{RoyalBlue}{ab\equiv 0}\equiv a^2\equiv b^2\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid a^2,b^2$.

So $p\mid d\mid a+c,b+c,a^2,b^2\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a,b,c$, and $(a,b,c)\ge 2$.

Comment: How do you deduce $a^2 \equiv b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{d}$ in your reasoning?

Comment: @A.P. $a\equiv b\implies ab\equiv a^2$

Answer (score 2):

Your findings so far are fine, but not (yet) fully conclusive towards the main problem.

Let $$C=\{\,c\in\mathbb Z^+\mid  \exists a,b\in\mathbb Z^+\colon a\ne b\land a+c| ab\land b+c| ab\,\}$$
be the set we are looking for.
For $c\ge 2$ we can let $$\tag{$\star$} a=c^3+c^2-c,\qquad b=c(a-1)=c(c+1)(c^2-1)$$Then certainly $0<a<b$ and we have
$$ab = c^2(c^2+c-1)(c+1)(c^2-1)=(a+c)(c^2+c-1)(c^2-1)$$
and 
$$ ab=ac(a-1)=(b+c)(a-1).$$
This shows $c\in C$ for $c\ge 2$.
On the other hand $1\notin C$ for if $a+1\mid ab$ then $\gcd(a+1,a)=1$ implies $a+1\mid b$; likewise $b+1\mid ab$ implies $b+1\mid a$. Specifically $b\ge a+1$ and $a\ge b+1$, which is absurd. Therefore we have 
$$C=\mathbb Z^+\setminus\{1\}.$$

---

Remains  to show that for each $c\in C$ there are only finitely many $(a,b)$.
*Empirically,* it seems that the choice for $a,b$ made in $(\star)$ is the maximal possible choice. Showing that $\max\{a,b\}>c(c+1)(c^2-1)$ is really impossible *would* of course show finiteness.

Comment: How do my findings imply $c\mid a,b$? I could see that if $c$ were prime, because $p\mid a,b,c\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid c\,\Rightarrow\,p=c$, but you later said we never used the assumption that $c$ is prime.

Comment: @user236182 Alright, we *did* use it there, but with hindsight, once we have found a way to compute suitable $a,b$ from given $c$, the proof that $a+c\mid ab$ and $b+c\mid ab$ does *not* use that $c$ is prime. - Maybe I should have dropped that paragraph altogether and started right away with the display formula.  But that would then feel like unmotivated and out of the blue, wouldn't it?

Comment: @A.P. Duely clarified and uncluttered

Comment: It is a decent solution of part 1 and we'll wait for someone to prove part 2. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. It is now considerably easier to understand your argument.

Comment: By trial and error, it seems that $a\le (c+1)^2c(c-1)$. If that's correct, it would imply finiteness. Still working on it

Comment: And before someone tries a dead-end: $a=315,b=65,c=10$ shows that neither $c\mid a$ nor $c\mid b$ needs to hold